# Working event code does not trigger anymore after first time use of Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I created a program to automatically send an email when a certain reminder pops up (at the beginning of each month). I tested the code a couple of times when I wrote it two weeks ago and it worked.

Now that the reminder does pop up for the first time "for real", it does not work.

I inserted a breakpoint in the only line of the Application_Reminder sub. The code never stops at the breakpoint, which for me indicates that the event is not triggered.

I tried googling. Why is the event not triggered and how can I get it triggered?

```vb
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
  SendAutoEmail Item
End Sub

Private Sub SendAutoEmail(Item As Object)
  Dim oTask As Outlook.TaskItem
  Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim oFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim ReminderSubject As String
  Dim EmailSubject As String
  Dim SendTo As String
  Dim Message As String
  Dim Signature As String
  
  'Task item
  ReminderSubject = "Project reminder"

  'Email
  SendTo = "Project team"
  EmailSubject = "Project progress"
  

  If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.TaskItem Then
    Set oTask = Item
    If LCase$(oTask.Subject) = LCase$(ReminderSubject) Then
      Message = "Test message"

      oTask.ReminderTime = DateAdd("m", 1, oTask.ReminderTime)
      oTask.Save

      Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
      oMail.Display
      Signature = oMail.Body
      oMail.Subject = EmailSubject
      oMail.Body = Message & vbCrLf & Signature
      oMail.Recipients.Add SendTo
      oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll
      oMail.Display
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to tag this question as solved?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use reminders to fire events can be problematic, and if the PC gets locked for a long time, it seems that the VBA can stop firing. Also if code is edited or an error is detected then Outlook will stop all VBA working and you need to close and reopen Outlook to re-initialise the VBA

You could try the following alternative code in the `ThisOutlookSession` module:

```
Private WithEvents MyReminders As Outlook.Reminders

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set MyReminders = Outlook.Application.Reminders
End Sub

Private Sub MyReminders_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderObject As Reminder)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call SendAutoEmail(ReminderObject.Item)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tragamor for the input. I'll keep the comments in mind. Even though they were not the root cause for my problem, they triggered my search in the right direction.

When I tried to create a test sub, I noted that macros were disabled, without any messagebox when firing up outlook. I probably did not run into this problem when I wrote the sub because this sub was the first macro in outlook on my device. My guess is that macros are not disabled by default if outlook finds no macros during startup. Therefore, I could develop and test the macro in a single session of outlook. In all subsequent sessions, outlook noticed vba code and disabled macros according to the settings in the Trust Center.

In order to get around that I had to google somewhat, therefore I'll post the answer here, even though it is not directly related to my question:
First step was to create a certificate with the program selfCert.exe. It might need to be executed as an administrator, I did not fully verify whether it is necessary but just did it. I found the program in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16 , but this seems to vary, because the google search returned other folders. I had to use the search function on the program files folder.

Next, the certificate needs to be added to the trusted publishers. (described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/af61b381-5631-437d-8f44-2a51856d2fd5/office-2016-selfcert-certificate-not-accepted-where-must-it-be-saved-to-be-recognized#b1680cd8-3d52-499a-879d-c3c83c567d4a))
This can be done in the internet options. However, I did not find the certificate as a single file on my computer in a form that could be imported. Therefore, I executed the command "mmc" in the command line, goto "add snap-in" (or similar, I work with German locale) choose "certificates snap-in", then "Own user account" (German description found [here](https://www.mcseboard.de/topic/75867-speicherort-der-zertifikate/))
Then, you can find the certificate that was created with selfcert.exe. With a right-click, it can be exported to a file and then be imported in the internet options to be added to the trusted publishers.
Last but not least, the macro needs to be signed with this certificate. If you now just close outlook and click "yes" when it asks if changes to the macro are to be saved, you might run into the problem described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/outlook/troubleshoot/deployment/macros-in-this-project-disabled-outlook). The solution is an only manual save in the vba editor, as also described in the link.
Now the macro works for me without having to reduce the general security settings in the trust center.